# Asynctask runtime error exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask

My android application stops working.Here's my asynctask class code

```
package com.example.hay;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AsyncLoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private Context mContext;
private ILoadDataListener mListener;

public AsyncLoadData(Context context, ILoadDataListener listener) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   try {
    String url = params[0];
    Document doc;   
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    String title = doc.text();
    return title;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    mListener.complete(result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mListener.loading();
}

public interface ILoadDataListener {
    void loading();

    void complete(String result);
}
}
```

It seems it's something wrong with my todo in background method.Logcat(i don't know how to post logcat log so i'll just paste it):

```
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.example.hay.AsyncLoadData.doInBackground(AsyncLoadData.java:26)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at com.example.hay.AsyncLoadData.doInBackground(AsyncLoadData.java:1)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-25 20:38:52.449: E/AndroidRuntime(878):  ... 5 more
```

Thanks guys
cheers

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Android can't locate `org.jsoup.Jsoup` - make sure you put it in the correct place so that it gets transferred with your application (that is, your `libs` folder)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable export for the JSoup jar. You can do that in the Project's properties.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're using Gradle make sure you have the correct dependency set up, otherwise make sure you have the JSoup jar in a location that it gets compiled in (libs dir on most IDEs though I think it's lib on eclipse). Make sure your application settings also specify that your app uses the dependency and it should be included on compile

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Eclipse, copy Jsoup.jar in your libs directory, if libs directory doesn't exist, make it yourself.

Right click your project -> build path -> configure build path -> Library tab -> add jar -> (find it in your libs) and add away